# Is it possible to indent JavaScript code in Notepad++?

Tags: javascript, notepad++, indentation, text-indent

I have some JavaScript code that is written in one line (no carriage returns), it's completely unreadable...

With Notepad++, I tried to replace these characters (`{`, `}`, `;`) by themselves plus a carriage return, but it still isn't very handy...

Is there a way to do this correctly in Notepad++?

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on how to do this in NP++, rather than to ask for a software recommendation. And voted to reopen.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think you want a code beautifier, this one looks quick and easy:
http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 196):

JSTool is the best for stability.

**Steps**:

1. Select menu Plugins>Plugin Manager>Show Plugin Manager
2. Check to JSTool checkbox > Install > Restart Notepad++
3. Open js file > Plugins > JSTool > JSFormat
   [image: screenshot]

Reference:

- Homepage: http://www.sunjw.us/jstoolnpp/
- Source code: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/

Comment: Just tried this today.  It worked perfectly. Nice simple explanation, thanks.

Comment: Awesome.. Its working. you can use it offline also. Bye bye JS beautifier

Comment: +10 , I used to do with online beautifier but this one is just perfect!

Comment: Nice. My only gripe is that it appears at the top of the list of Plugins, which I believe is sorted alphabetically by file name of all things. Certainly a much smaller inconvenience than manually formatting source code or copying and pasting into a web page, though!

Answer (score 51):

Try the notepad++ plugin JSMinNpp(Changed name to JSTool since 1.15)

http://www.sunjw.us/jsminnpp/

Answer (score 7):

Use [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org) instead of trying to do it manually.

Answer (score 7):

Could you use online services like [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/) ?

**Update:** (as per request)

Google chrome will do this also http://cristian-radulescu.ro/article/pretty-print-javascript-with-google-chrome.html

Comment: Arh, beaten too it. Sorry. Google chrome will do this also http://cristian-radulescu.ro/article/pretty-print-javascript-with-google-chrome.html

Comment: Didn't know that trick on chrome, is is useful too, thank you

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh I'd love to see your comment pulled into your answer. It's applies to any webkit browser, and there's no need for an external service.